# CSS - positioning a pseudo-element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have problem positioning this after pseudo element. If I try positioning it, it won't be responsive. 
This is what I have:

```
.intro>h1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -140px;
  width: 100px;
  left: calc(50% - 50px);
  border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(49, 42, 96, 1);
}
```

[image: It display normally now]
[image: But it does not display well on the mobile]

It positions normally when on desktop, but does not position well on the mobile.

How can I fix this, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: jsfiddle! make a demo

Comment: can you please provied full code or demo link

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Overflow. We are a traditional, community-driven Q&A platform, committed to providing [quality answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to [quality questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that include a [mcve] in the form of a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Can YOu Please Provide the Demo Link Where Can We Understand What Actually You Do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this

```
.intro>h1::after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    width: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(49, 42, 96, 1);
}
h1{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Good work on the guesswork. OP, please still read the provided links in the comments above and provide a [mcve] with your next question. Cheers.

Comment: Ya it was a done with a guess @domdom. So please provide a snippet next time.@o.danielcoker

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
.intro>h1::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(49, 42, 96, 1);
}
```